# How to export site page

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, modern-pages, sitepages, migration

I want to move a SharePoint Online page to another site, so I want to export and import.

Does anyone know anything about how to migrate site page?

Any information would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no direct OOTB way to move site pages from one site to another site in SharePoint online modern experience.

You can try other workarounds as suggested in below references like using Power Automate or PnP PowerShell.

1. [Copy or Move Site Page from one site to another](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/copy-or-move-site-page-from-one-site-to-another/m-p/255703) - Using Power Automate
2. [SharePoint Online - Copy site pages between site collections - is that possible?](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/office-365/sharepoint-online-copy-site-pages-between-site-collections-is/m-p/1258915) - Using PnP PowerShell

**Microsoft documentation reference**: [Move-PnPFile](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/move-pnpfile?view=sharepoint-ps)

If you want Microsoft to implement this functionality in SharePoint Online in near future then you can vote and support below idea:

[Add the ability to copy a modern site page from one site to another](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/35035618-add-the-ability-to-copy-a-modern-site-page-from-on)

Answer (score 0):

One way you can try is to use the send to function in classic experience to copy the page to your new site.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it, but it didn't succeed.
Even if I look at the imported page, it is not displayed normally.